# Which Unix don't have a thread-safe malloc?

Tags: c, multithreading

I want my C program to be portable even on very old Unix OS but the problem is that I'm using pthreads and dynamic allocation (malloc). All Unix I know of have a thread-safe malloc (Linux, *BSD, Irix, Solaris) however this is not guaranteed by the C standard, and I'm sure there are very old versions where this is not true.

So, is there some list of platforms that I'd need to wrap malloc() calls with a mutex lock? I plan to write a ./configure test that checks if current platform is in that list.

The other alternative would be to test malloc() for thread-safety, but I know of no deterministic way to do this. Any ideas on this one too?

Comment: This question is relevant for programmers only and thus should be asked on stackoverflow. It will probably get migrated there.

Comment: Very old Unix won't have `pthreads` at all...

Comment: The C standard doesn't have threads - that's why it's not "guaranteed". Posix, which among other things defines pthreads does guarantee it.

Comment: @nos: s/doesn't/didn't/; C11 has threads.

Comment: How old is 'very old' Unix?  Anything from this millennium is practically certain to have thread-safety because POSIX threads were defined in the early to mid 90s.  Indeed, anything that doesn't have a thread-safe `malloc()` probably doesn't have threads either...Are you sure you're worrying about a real problem?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler early 90s, this piece of software carries a heavy legacy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only C standard that has threads (and can thus is relevant to your question) is C11, which states:

> For purposes of determining the existence of a data race, memory
>   allocation functions behave as though they accessed only memory
>   locations accessible through their arguments and not other static
>   duration storage.

Or in other words, as long as two threads don't pass the same address to `realloc` or `free` all calls to the memory functions are thread safe.

For POSIX, that is all Unix'es that you can find nowadays you have:

> Each function defined in the System Interfaces volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 is thread-safe unless explicitly stated otherwise.

I don't know from where you take your assertion that `malloc` wouldn't be thread safe for older Unixes, a system with threads that doesn't implement that thread safe is pretty much useless. What might be a problem on such an older system is performance, but it should always be functional.

Comment: Thanks! So I suppose all Unix supporting pthreads are supposed to have thread-safe `malloc()`. But as I'm searching the internet I've found that implementation for some versions is buggy, for example see [here](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6952) and [here](http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2009-1202.html). So it's quite possible I'll write the `./configure` test to avoid such crashes.

Comment: @jimis, the first link you are pointing to is not a bug that makes the program not functioning, just a memory leak :) The second one has not much information, so I can't tell. But these are **bugs** of systems where `malloc` is intended to be thread safe, not implementations of threads that don't have a thread safe `malloc`. All users of such systems **must** update, anyhow. With your own software you shouldn't chase any possible bug that might have existed in some version of some system. With such an approach, almost no progress would be possible.